# How to make vim spell error search the current line only?

Tags: search, spell-checking

This vim binding will make `<C-l>` correct the previous spelling mistake:

```
inoremap <C-l> <c-g>u<Esc>[s1z=`]a<c-g>u
```

How do I modify it to make it correct the previous mistake on the current line only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
inoremap <C-l> <c-g>u<Esc>:call <sid>fixLineSpellError()<cr>`]a<c-g>u

function! s:fixLineSpellError()
  " get current line number
  let lnum = line('.')
  " find last misspelled word before cursor
  normal! [s
  " do nothing if line changed
  if lnum != line('.') | return | endif
  " fix spell error if line doesn't change
  normal! 1z=
endfunction
```

Map break down:

- `<c-g>u<Esc>` break undo sequence, switch to normal mode.
- `:call <sid>fixLineSpellError()<cr>` call a script scope function to fix current line spell error.
- `` `]a `` move cursor back to the end of last change, start to append.
- `<c-g>u` break undo sequence.

Comment: Works as intended and well explained, thanks!